# How do i root on galaxy j5

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung, twrp

I want root on my samsung galaxy j5 without pc. I can't root with 1 click root the one click root are all bad for this phone. I don't have twrp.Is any way to get root access with that phone? I don't have pc now.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without a computer. You need a computer and Odin (Heimdall) to root your device

Comment: I don't think you can do without pc. You need to have a pc in order to root.